# Extract all exceptions of particular type with stack traces in Java log

Tags: java, perl, parsing, exception, logging

I want to extract all the exceptions of a particular type, say AbandonedObjectException from my java web app log files. I found a perl script which can extract all exceptions, but not sure how to filter for exception I want. I know this can be done using a script but trying to find if there is any that is already existing.

```
perl -n -e 'm/(Exception)|(\tat )/ && print' catalina.out > catLog
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use `grep`?

```
grep AbandonedObjectException catalina.out > catLog
```

Comment: That will only give the exception line, but not the stack trace.